# Как решить проблему зависания шариков друг в друге?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, геометрия, обработка-столкновений

Шарики можно создавать кликом на поле, но для иллюстрации проблемы уже заранее создал 2 шарика.

При движении шарики могут войти друг в друга, сработает механизм отталкивания, который поменяет векторы движения шариков, но шарики могут не успеть выйти и тогда будет зависание. Либо шарики может натыкать пользователь и они тоже окажутся друг-в-друге.

Зависание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Минимальный пример:

```
import math
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QTimer


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, pos, r=25):
        self.x = pos.x()
        self.y = pos.y()
        self.r = r

        self.dx = self.dy = 0
        while self.dx == 0 and self.dy == 0:
            self.dx = randint(-3, 3)
            self.dy = randint(-3, 3)

        self.color = QColor(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))

    @property
    def center(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    @property
    def top(self):
        return self.y - self.r

    @property
    def bottom(self):
        return self.y + self.r

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.x - self.r

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.x + self.r

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy

    def is_collide(self, other):
        dx = self.x - other.x
        dy = self.y - other.y
        return math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) < self.r + other.r

    def draw(self, painter):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(self.color)

        painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(self.x, self.y), self.r, self.r)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._on_timeout)
        self.timer.setInterval(30)
        self.timer.start()

        self.balls = [
            Ball(QPointF(200, 200)),
            Ball(QPointF(220, 220))
        ]

    def _on_timeout(self):
        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.move()

            # Отталкивание от стены
            if ball.left <= 0 or ball.right >= self.width():
                # Возврат шарика, если тот в стене
                if ball.left < 0:
                    ball.x = 0 + ball.r
                if ball.right > self.width():
                    ball.x = self.width() - ball.r

                ball.dx *= -1

            # Отталкивание от стены
            if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= self.height():
                # Возврат шарика, если тот в стене
                if ball.top < 0:
                    ball.y = 0 + ball.r
                if ball.bottom > self.height():
                    ball.y = self.height() - ball.r

                ball.dy *= -1

        num = len(self.balls)
        # Проверка столкнования шариков
        for i in range(num):
            for j in range(i + 1, num):
                if self.balls[i].is_collide(self.balls[j]):
                    self.balls[i].dx, self.balls[j].dx = self.balls[j].dx, self.balls[i].dx
                    self.balls[i].dy, self.balls[j].dy = self.balls[j].dy, self.balls[i].dy

        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ball = Ball(event.pos())
        self.balls.append(ball)
        self.update()
    
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.draw(painter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Думаю, нужно сделать так, чтобы шарики отталкивались друг от друга на расстояние, на которое они успели войти друг в друга, но с идеей алгоритма возникли проблемы.

Накидал, примерно как это представляю (красная линия, это то, насколько шарики вошли в друг друга, стрелки это направление их векторов):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD.** Пробовал сделать шаг назад при столкновении шариков перед изменением векторов, но это **не** помогло:

```
    def move_back(self):
        self.x -= self.dx
        self.y -= self.dy
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...

        for i in range(num):
            for j in range(i + 1, num):
                if self.balls[i].is_collide(self.balls[j]):
                    self.balls[i].move_back()
                    self.balls[j].move_back()
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

                    self.balls[i].dx, self.balls[j].dx = self.balls[j].dx, self.balls[i].dx
                    self.balls[i].dy, self.balls[j].dy = self.balls[j].dy, self.balls[i].dy
```

**UPD2.** Либо шаг дальше после изменения векторов, тоже **не** помогло:

```
                    self.balls[i].dx, self.balls[j].dx = self.balls[j].dx, self.balls[i].dx
                    self.balls[i].dy, self.balls[j].dy = self.balls[j].dy, self.balls[i].dy

                    self.balls[i].move()
                    self.balls[j].move()
```

**UPD3.** Удалось **частично** решить проблему, но это дикий костыль и шарики, при вхождении друг в друга далеко перемещаются и это может вызвать цепную реакцию. Тут я попробовал узнать насколько большое расстояние между шариками и если оно меньшей значения одного из радиусов, то обоим шарикам давалось перемещение:

```
        # Проверка столкнования шариков
        for i in range(num):
            for j in range(i + 1, num):
                if self.balls[i].is_collide(self.balls[j]):
                    dx = self.balls[i].x - self.balls[j].x
                    dy = self.balls[i].y - self.balls[j].y
                    d = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
                    
                    self.balls[i].dx, self.balls[j].dx = self.balls[j].dx, self.balls[i].dx
                    self.balls[i].dy, self.balls[j].dy = self.balls[j].dy, self.balls[i].dy

                    if d < self.balls[i].r * 1.8:
                        self.balls[i].x += -d * (1 if self.balls[i].dx < 0 else -1)
                        self.balls[i].y += -d * (1 if self.balls[i].dy < 0 else -1)

                        self.balls[j].x += -d * (1 if self.balls[j].dx < 0 else -1)
                        self.balls[j].y += -d * (1 if self.balls[j].dy < 0 else -1)
```

**UPD4.** Тоже обход, но на этот раз создания шариков пользователем. Тут, в событии клика мышки проверяем, что новый шарик не пересекается с другими:

```
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ball = Ball(event.pos())
        if any(x.has_collide(ball) for x in self.balls):
            return

        self.balls.append(ball)
        self.update()
```

Comment: Фигня какая-то... что, при достаточных начальных скоростях при движении строго по одной прямой они вообще смогут пролететь друг сквозь друга? как получается, что они проникают друг в друга? А если они могут войти частично, то делай два диаметра. Малый - твёрдое ядро, не допускающее взаимопроникновения, и внешний отображаемый (грубо "планета" и "атмосфера"). Соответственно они смогут друг в друга "влипнуть" не более чем на разность этих диаметров.

Comment: @Akina, тем не менее, это происходит :) Особенно, когда шариков становится много и они отталкиваясь друг от друга и от стенок начинают друг в друга зависать. Я могу сделать так, чтобы при движении была проверка столкнования, а само движение было не на значение вектора на более малое, в цикле, типа вектор x = 3, я сделаю 6 итераций по 0.5 и на каждой проверю на столкнование, но мне кажется это выглядит сложнее чем нужно сделать, плюс не решит проблему, когда пользователь натыкал шарики друг на друге (хотя ее и можно тоже решить, запретив такое делать)

Comment: Мне кажется, проблема коллайдинга не такая уж простая. Может лучше готовый движок какой-то использовать, который умеет это всё считать или хочется самому с нуля написать это дело? :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, хочется самому :) Хочется вспомнить кое-что... Давно, на практике 3-го курса, делал на с++/qt подобное задание, только шарики поглощали друг друга, если у одного радиус больше чем у другого, увеличиваясь в размере

Comment: А что если в случае коллайда после изменения векторов движения сразу `move` делать обоим шарикам? И ещё мне кажется именно обмен векторами как-то не совсем правильно выглядит, должно как-то хитрее обрабатываться. И ещё, я не очень представляю, что будет в случае множественного столкновения нескольких шариков, мне кажется фигня какая-то может в целом получиться в этом случае.

Comment: @CrazyElf, попробовал, но не получилось UPD1 / UPD2 :)

Comment: А что если попробовать считать вот этот вектор между центрами шариков и задавать им вектор движения по линии, проходящей по этой линии между центрами шариков? Тогда вне зависимости от того, как шарики двигались  до столкновения, даже если они стояли на месте (пользователь натыкал) они начнут двигаться друг от друга. Ну там ещё со стенками могут быть проблемы, но всё-равно какой-то шарик у которого есть рядом свободное пространство должен начать улетать, а там и второй за ним.

Comment: @CrazyElf, с этим как раз и проблемы возникли, поэтому и задал вопрос :) UPD3

Comment: Я что-то подобное делал, при пересечении "шариков" создается сила Гука пропорциональная "деформации" (условно считалось что шарики деформировались на столько, насколько расстояние между ними меньше суммы радиусов, ну и шарики фактически считаются как бы стержнями))). За счет подбора коэффициента упругости можно добиться, чтобы цепная реакция была не взрывной, а более-менее мягкой. Ну и при наличии внешних сил вполне допустима будет ситуация, что шарики слегка между собой пересекаются (пропорционально приложенной силе).

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за подсказку :)

Comment: Можно глянуть этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling Вообще идея состоит в том, чтобы заранее на следующем кадре выявить столкновение и заранее рассчитать положение, а не в момент когда шары уже вошли друг в друга. Особенно текущая проблема будет видна, если скорость шаров будет увеличиваться.

Comment: @AlexKrass, спасибо, посмотрю :)

Comment: Еще вариант, это в момент когда обнаружили столкновение, посчитать `dt = d / (v1+v2)` - промежуток времени, когда реально произошло столкновение, и рассчитать правильные координаты шаров в данное время. Нужно посчитать сколько каждый прошел после столкновения (проникая друг в друга, что неправильно), отмотать назад, и вместо этого посчитать сколько он прошел бы с новой скоростью в направлении после столкновения за `dt`.

Comment: А вообще-то тут большая проблема, когда происходит сразу два столкновения на одном шаге симуляции. Боюсь нужно находить сразу все события что случились с предыдущего шага и сразу все их учитывать рассчитывая новые координаты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код поправить не сложно: надо менять скорости шаров только если они сближаются.
Это касается и столкновений между шарами и столкновений шара со стенкой.

Если пользователь создаст пересекающиеся шары, ничего делать не надо. Они самостоятельно выйдут из пересечения через некоторое время.

В коде ниже исправлены удары о стены и взаимные удары между шарами:

```
import math
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QTimer


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, pos, r=25):
        self.x = pos.x()
        self.y = pos.y()
        self.r = r

        self.dx = self.dy = 0
        while self.dx == 0 and self.dy == 0:
            self.dx = randint(-3, 3)
            self.dy = randint(-3, 3)

        self.color = QColor(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))

    @property
    def center(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    @property
    def top(self):
        return self.y - self.r

    @property
    def bottom(self):
        return self.y + self.r

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.x - self.r

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.x + self.r

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy

    def is_collide(self, other):
        dx = self.x - other.x
        dy = self.y - other.y
        return math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) < self.r + other.r

    def draw(self, painter):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(self.color)

        painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(self.x, self.y), self.r, self.r)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._on_timeout)
        self.timer.setInterval(30)
        self.timer.start()

        self.balls = [
            Ball(QPointF(200, 200)),
            Ball(QPointF(220, 220))
        ]

    def _on_timeout(self):
        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.move()

            # Отталкивание от левой стены
            if ball.left <= 0:
                if ball.dx < 0:
                    ball.dx = -ball.dx

            # Отталкивание от правой стены
            if ball.right >= self.width():
                if ball.dx > 0:
                    ball.dx = -ball.dx

            # Отталкивание от верхней стены
            if ball.top <= 0:
                if ball.dy < 0:
                    ball.dy = -ball.dy

            # Отталкивание от нижней стены
            if ball.bottom >= self.height():
                if ball.dy > 0:
                    ball.dy = -ball.dy

        num = len(self.balls)
        # Проверка столкнования шариков
        for i in range(num):
            for j in range(i + 1, num):
                if self.balls[i].is_collide(self.balls[j]):
                    # вектор из центра шара i в центр шара j
                    pij = [self.balls[j].x - self.balls[i].x, self.balls[j].y - self.balls[i].y]
                    # скорость шара j относительно шара i
                    vij = [self.balls[j].dx - self.balls[i].dx, self.balls[j].dy - self.balls[i].dy]
                    # скалярное произведение векторов
                    # если оно отрицательно, шары сближаются
                    # только в этом случае надо менять скорости
                    if pij[0] * vij[0] + pij[1] * vij[1] < 0:
                        self.balls[i].dx, self.balls[j].dx = self.balls[j].dx, self.balls[i].dx
                        self.balls[i].dy, self.balls[j].dy = self.balls[j].dy, self.balls[i].dy

        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ball = Ball(event.pos())
        self.balls.append(ball)
        self.update()
    
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.draw(painter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Спасибо, решение! А в двух словах, что вы сделали, чтобы было "хорошо"? :) Как я понимаю, в случаи с стенами, делаем проверку выхода и вектора движения, так чтобы при выходе за стену, шарик не менял вектор пока не выйдет обратно. А вот алгоритм с шариками непонятный :)

Comment: Я добавил комментарии в код. Идея та же: меняем скорости только если шары сближаются. Если шары уже удаляются, ничего делать не нужно, только ждать.

Answer (score 4):

Позволил себе несколько модернизировать не только тот участок кода который касался вашего вопроса, так что выкладываю весь код целиком с повторениями и комментариями по моим переделкам

```py
# Убрал библиотеку math так как считаю нецелосообразным её использование
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QTimer


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, pos, r=25):
        self.x = pos.x()
        self.y = pos.y()
        self.r = r

        self.dx = self.dy = 0
        while self.dx == 0 and self.dy == 0:
            self.dx = randint(-3, 3)
            self.dy = randint(-3, 3)

        self.color = QColor(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))

    @property
    def center(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    @property
    def top(self):
        return self.y - self.r

    @property
    def bottom(self):
        return self.y + self.r

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.x - self.r

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.x + self.r

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy

    def is_collide(self, other):
        dx = self.x - other.x
        dy = self.y - other.y
        # Переписано выражение return (убрана библиотека math, несколько ускорилось вычесление)
        return (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** .5 <= self.r + other.r

    def crash_move(self, other):
        # Метод обменивающий ускорения при столкновении
        # Почситал его перенос в класс шаров здравой идеей
        self.dx, other.dx = other.dx, self.dx
        self.dy, other.dy = other.dy, self.dy

    def crash_corrector(self, other, speed_drop=1):
        """
        :param other: ball class
        :param speed_drop: Коэффициент уменьшения силы отталкивания
        :return: добавочные x и y
        """
        x = self.x - other.x
        x /= speed_drop
        y = self.y - other.y
        y /= speed_drop
        return {'x': x, 'y': y}

    def draw(self, painter):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(self.color)

        painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(self.x, self.y), self.r, self.r)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._on_timeout)
        self.timer.setInterval(30)
        self.timer.start()

        self.balls = [
            Ball(QPointF(200, 200)),
            Ball(QPointF(200, 210))
        ]

    def _on_timeout(self):
        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.move()

            # Отталкивание от стены
            if ball.left <= 0 or ball.right >= self.width():
                # Возврат шарика, если тот в стене
                if ball.left < 0:
                    ball.x = 0 + ball.r
                elif ball.right > self.width():  
                    # if замена на elif [ради оптимизации скорости выполнения]
                    ball.x = self.width() - ball.r

                ball.dx *= -1

            # Отталкивание от стены
            if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= self.height():
                # Возврат шарика, если тот в стене
                if ball.top < 0:
                    ball.y = 0 + ball.r
                elif ball.bottom > self.height(): 
                    # if замена на elif [ради оптимизации скорости выполнения]
                    ball.y = self.height() - ball.r

                ball.dy *= -1
            # Новый метод для обработки столкновений
            self.ball_collide(ball=ball)
            """
            Целиком убран дополнительный for с проверкой 
            в силу того что аналогичную пробежку 
            по шарикам выполняем выше [опять оптимизация]
            """

        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ball = Ball(event.pos())
        self.balls.append(ball)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.draw(painter)

    def ball_collide(self, ball):
        # Проверяем коллизию с каждым шаром от текущего присланного из главного цикла
        for check_ball in self.balls:
            # Проверяем колизию и проверяем что шар не отношению к самому себе
            if check_ball.is_collide(ball) and check_ball != ball:
                check_ball.crash_move(ball) # производим обмен "силами"
                k = check_ball.crash_corrector(ball, speed_drop=10)  # Считаем поправки
                # Двигаем шарик и перерисовываем (Условно защита от диких разгонов)
                check_ball.move()
                self.update()
                if check_ball.is_collide(ball):
                    check_ball.dx += k['x'] # Применяем поправки и опять перерисовываем
                    check_ball.dy += k['y']
                    ball.dx -= k['x']
                    ball.dy -= k['y']
                    ball.move()
                    check_ball.move()
                    self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Спасибо, хорошее решение, буду с ним разбираться :) Кст, для `crash_corrector` можно не словарь вернуть, а кортеж, т.е. `return x, y`, тогда при вызове: `kx, ky = check_ball.crash_corrector(ball, speed_drop=10)`, ну и заменить `k['x']` и `k['y']` на `kx` и `ky`. А `speed_drop=10` был получен опытным путем?

Comment: @gil9red По поводу возврата кортежа я чёт не подумал, действительно так было бы лучше. И `speed_drop=10` действительно получен опытным путём, показалось самым оптимальным.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение, но я принял другой ответ, т.к. в нем при столкновении шариков не происходит наращивания скорости шариков (выглядит это здорово)